# highcharts, loading an image in tooltip

Tags: javascript

I have this javascrpit code which suppose to load different image to tooltip reading the url from **data** as mouse hover that value, if I write that url myself the image loads just fine but when I pass the exact url to my code it won't load!, the url here is in string **n**.
Any help please.

```
tooltip: {
useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {                        
        var str = this.point.marker.symbol;
        str = str.substring(0, str.length -1);
        var n=str.slice(4);
        //return '<img class="" src="n"/>';
        return '<img src ="http://cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/122.png" 
               width=\"64px\" height=\"64px\"/><br>'+
               'Expected answer: <b>'+ this.point.answer +'</b><br/>';
           }
       },
```

Here is jsfiddle code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khalifa/kktwdwf6/3/)

Comment: Could you create a small jsfiddle for it?

Comment: I tried but I wasn't able to make it work at all, I mean the chart won't load anyway!

Comment: Based on the fiddle, you aren't actually injecting the URL into your image tag. `'<img src ="+n+"/><br>' +` should actually look like `'<img src ="'+n+'"/><br>' +`. You want to add the double quotes into the string, but also escape the string so that you can concat the variable n into it.

Comment: @ Nick Wyman Thank you so much, it works.